# is it possible to write a generic trigger with parametrized table name in it?

Tags: triggers, sybase

i have to add trigger to multiple tables but they all basically write to an audit table when insert, update, delete are triggered.

the only change really is the table name on the "create trigger" line.
i am wondering if it is possible to write something like "

```
create trigger {@@table_}trigger on @@table for insert, update, delete
```

I am trying to replace {@@table_}trigger with the ${tableName_}trigger. i.e. if a table is name userTable, it would be userTable_trigger.

I would appreciate if someone can point out if this is feasible at all. as far as I can tell from the doc, it doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: they also same number and name of columns? this is not possible as far as I know

Comment: you should write a tool in perl, shell or whatever that takes a proforma trigger and generates each instance you need.  Or maybe use the old "sqsh" sql tool perhaps - that has variables.